# rtabmap error:[ERROR]: Skipping XML Document ".../nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
when i run rtabmap this error is occure and in localization mood map is not load:
[ERROR] [1517006470.211027541]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.

my ubuntu is 14.04 LTS and ros indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280987/rtabmap-error:%5Berror%5D-%5B1517006470.211027541%5D:-skipping-xml-document-%22/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml%22-which-had-no-root-element.--this-likely-means-the-xml-is-malformed-or-missing./) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q274849.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1